# Are multiple filter options good for mobile?

Tags: usability, responsive-design, user-centered-design

We are designing a responsive web app which contains dynamic data. We have a huge variety of filters(Nested) like Location(all countries), founded year, Sectors(Practice area, Feeds, Business models), investors, Acquired by, funded date e.t.c  We also have search based filters.  How good is it to show these many filters in mobile? If it is good please share your ideas with some examples.  Thank you :)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here is the solution which can you consider while having more number of filters. There are no predefined principles for the filters but if you have to give more attributes and have no option then you can keep it as I have designed below.

Hope this will help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to merge the possible options of each filter. **Display each filter only in one line**: the title + result or the title + option (if it is possible to reduce the selection to it, for example a slider or a switch button). Take as an example Android OS settings. You can rely on [dialogs](https://www.material.io/guidelines/components/dialogs.html#dialogs-confirmation-dialogs) for the option selection and use different types such as [menus](https://www.material.io/guidelines/components/menus.html), [pickers](https://www.material.io/guidelines/components/pickers.html#pickers-date-pickers), etc.

[image]
[image]